# SQL error while installing concrete5 on my localhost

Tags: php, mysql, concrete5

Facing this error while installing `concrete5` on my localhost:

> Function mysql_connect() not found. Your system does not appear to have MySQL available within PHP.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your server is likely running PHP 7.0.0, which removed the `mysql_*` functions entirely. Please see the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.requirements.phphttp://php.net/manual/en/mysql.requirements.php), and in particular the red dialog at the top of the page:

> **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)
>   extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and
>   [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

Comment: thanks for answering, i just removed comment from php.ini file and it was fixed.

Comment: @Farhan which comment did you remove from php.ini? I am trying to move a concrete5 website from an old synology nas to a new one running php7.2, and am facing the same problem